# Kendo UI how to read data in the model passing from Spring MVC Controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, model, kendo-ui, controller, datasource

The data in Controller:

```
model.addAttribute("colors", colorList);
```

In the jsp file, how to get the "colors" in the Kendo UI scripts?

```
    $("#color").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        dataSource: **${colors}**,
        index: 0,
        change: onChange
    });
```

Please give suggestions without "kendo-jsp style"(kendo:dataSource) and "transport-read" ways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needless to answer this silly question: convert the colorList to json in Controller ...

Answer (score 0):

hope this can help you. happy coding bro.

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: $.parseJSON('${colors}') 
    });
```